# Upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.2 : Cookies data no longer readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm migrating a Rails 4.2 application to Rails 5.2.

In the code, we are setting a cookie:

```
cookies.permanent.signed["wsid#{session[:user_id]}".to_sym] = { value: wsid, httponly: true }
```

And then fetching it back with:

```
cookies.permanent.signed["wsid#{session[:user_id]}".to_sym]
```

After having upgraded Rails, the value is no longer readable.

After double checking [the Upgrading Ruby on Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), I found out that migrating from Rails 5.1 to 5.2, [there is a change for cookies](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#expiry-in-signed-or-encrypted-cookie-is-now-embedded-in-the-cookies-values).

So I added to all the environment files the following :

```
  # controls whether signed and encrypted cookies use the AES-256-GCM cipher or
  # the older AES-256-CBC cipher. It defaults to true.
  config.action_dispatch.use_authenticated_cookie_encryption = false
```

but I still can't access the values.

Can anyone help me on this please?

### Update

I read about the `secret_key_base` and I understood that `cookies` is encrypting the data under the hood but actually the values defined by the above code seems to not be encrypted because using `Base64.decode64` I can see the right value.